# Plot table within subplot - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is it possible to plot a table within specific subplot. Using the example below, I'd like the table to be inserted into `ax1`. Rather than `ax3`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,6))

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace = 0.4, hspace = 0.3)
gridsize = (3, 2)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan = 2, rowspan = 2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 0), colspan = 1, rowspan = 1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 1), colspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

ax1.set_xlim(0,10)
ax1.set_ylim(0,10)

xy = 5,5
Oval = mpl.patches.Circle(xy, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.2)
ax1.add_patch(Oval)

table = plt.table(cellText= [[''],['']],
    colWidths = [0.2],
    rowLabels=['row','row'],
    colLabels=[''],
    bbox = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.table`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html) method, which allows you to add a table to a specific `Axes` instance instead of to the 'current' instance as `matplotlib.pyplot.table` does. The usage is identical.

```
table = ax1.table(cellText= [[''],['']],
    colWidths = [0.2],
    rowLabels=['row','row'],
    colLabels=[''],
    bbox = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5])
```